# change URLRequests by XML, as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

An other XML and Flash question. *How do I change my URLRequests by XML?* My problem may be something else, but this only happens when I use the XML variable. Thanks.

URLRequest by XML

```
var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
/*OUTPUT
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
*/
```

URLRequest by name FILE LOADS, WORKS FINE

```
var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("bite.swf");
/*OUTPUT
"bite.swf"
*/
```

COMPLETE SWF

```
//LISTEN AND LOAD XML
var myXML:*;
var myLoad:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoad.load(new URLRequest("visibleAdv.xml"));
myLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseXML);
//PARSE XML
function parseXML(e:Event):void {
myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
//XML VARIABLE
var url:String = (myXML.Lt.text());
trace(url);
//LOAD SWF
var ld:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(ld);
var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("bite.swf");//"bite.swf"
ld.load(bgURL);
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SESSION>
<Lt TITLE="stage.stageHeight">"bite.swf"</Lt>
</SESSION>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a problem with the code. It's more likely that you don't have your xml file in the right place so URLoader can't find it.  Also you don't need to wrap bite.swf in ". Just <Lt TITLE="stage.stageHeight">bite.swf</Lt> is fine.

Comment: @James, it looks right, I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML**
Take away the quotations from "bite.swf"

```
<Lt TITLE="stage.stageHeight">bite.swf</Lt>
```

**SWF** This should work fine now

```
var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
```

Comment: @pixelGreaser, It's already cast as string, so you don't need the quotes around it.